# How to run c code in Linux if linux is installed on usb

Tags: c, linux

I've installed Linux mint on usb as my hard drive got really slow. Now I want to compile and run C code. I successfully compiled it but as linux is in usb and I've to store program in one of my hard drive NTFS/FAT partitions so I'm getting bash permission denied error what should I do to run the code? I cannot store the program in usb(Linux partition)

Comment: Simplest way would be calling `/lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./your_program`.

Comment: @keltar-What this `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` is for. Please explain a bit, I wanna know more of it.

Comment: The real problem here is that you need to install Linux Mint with persistence.  It will let you keep files on the USB across reboots.  You can use a tool like uNetBootin to accomplish this.

Comment: Yeah dude,you need persistent USB installed linux-ditsro for it probably!

Comment: @shekharsuman ELF binaries don't usually get executed by themselves. They use so-called "interpreter" - some file that executes them. When you run binary, kernel parses ELF header, finds path to interpreter and attempts to launch it with your program as argument. Default interpreter on linux is usually `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`; since there is no execution rights on file, automated launch wouldn't work, but you still can launch interpreter manually and pass your binary as parameter. Quite the same happens with scripts - for text files interpreter specified as `#!/path/to/interpreter` instead.

Comment: Still got the same error..

Comment: @Krypton how you've compiled your program and what is exact error message, as well as `ls -l ./your_program` output?

Comment: _Which_ permission error? Can you post the actual text of the error?

Comment: @keltar-Thanks man,understood somewhat!

Comment: @Lama Can I mount my FAT or NTFS drive and change permission bit so that I can execute my program? if not then I'll try your first solution and install linux mint with persistence. Thanks

Comment: @Krypton also you cound try adding `-o fmask=0000` to mount options for your vfat/ntfs partition, so all files on that file system will be treated as having full read-write-execute rights.

Answer (score 3):

Probably your problem is that the NFS/VFAT systems are mounted with the `noexec` flag or maybe the `showexec` flag. It instruct the kernel not to run any executable from these partitions (a security measure).

If it is `showexec`, then it is simply a matter of naming your executable with an `.exe`, `.com` or `.bat` extension (yes, even if it is a Linux executable, the vfat driver uses the extension to infer the executable permission bit).

If it is `noexec`, read on...

On older kernels you could bypass this with the `/ld-*.so` trick, but as `man mount` comments:

> **noexec**: [...] (Until recently it was possible to run  binaries  anyway  using  a command like /lib/ld*.so /mnt/binary. This trick fails since Linux 2.4.25 / 2.6.0.)

If my guess is correct, you have several options:

A. Remove the flag from the partition, with this command as root:

```
mount -o remount,exec <mount-point>
```

B. Find out why your partitions have this flag, which program does it (`gnome-disks` or whatever) and change it.

C. Compile your program to another partition, if not in the USB partition, then for example in a `tmpfs`:

```
mkdir exe
sudo mount -t tmpfs exe exe
```

And then, when you compile your program:

```
gcc test.c -o exe/test
```

But beware! A `tmpfs` is volatile and will disappear when you umount it or shut down the machine. You can make a permanent partition-in-a-file:

```
truncate -s 512M exe.img
mkfs.ext4 exe.img
mkdir exe
```

Then, to mount the image each time you boot the machine:

```
sudo mount -o loop exe.img exe
```

Comment: I like the hidden-at-the-end solution best, in which you create a linux partition inside the Windows one. You should make this more prominent.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the file to `/tmp`, set the execute permission, and you should be good to go, until you reboot and then you'll have to repeat it.

```
cp /path/to/wherever/myprogram /tmp/myprogram
chmod +x /tmp/myprogram
/tmp/myprogram
```

Comment: This solution was for a one-off problem. If you want to do this is repeatedly then I'd recommend making a Linux disk file as @rodrigo suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I Had same program this is what worked, for a console HELLO WORLD test on Debian Linux.

Simply compiled with syntax:
gcc hello.c -o hello.exe

Compiled in an instant and ran program at command line
via:.        ./hello.exe